# Rackspace yum install git cURL 443 Connection refused

Tags: git, rackspace, bitbucket

Trying to install git in a RHEL Rackspace Dedicated Server, but am getting the following after typing in this command:  `yum install git`

> Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for
> https://rhui.rackspace.com/pulp/mirror//content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/appstream/os
> [Failed to connect to rhui.rackspace.com port 443: Connection refused]

Could this be a firewall issue?  This is from a clean build.  I have the same problem with trying to do a `yum install openssl-dev`

Curl is installed, but not sure why it's refusing to connect.  Is there anyways to get the files on the server linked to a repository on bitbucket through git?  This seems like this should be pretty basic stuff to me.  Not sure why it's even trying to connect to a rackspace url? Apologies if this is a dumb question, but have looked everywhere for help on this and doesn't seem to be anything online about this.  The videos I watched show it working as expected.  I even tried installing the dependencies and can't get that to work either `yum install git-core`

I have also tried the following:

`wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.33.1.zip`

`unzip v2.33.1.zip`

`cd git-2.33.1/`

`make prefix=/usr/local all install`

This method works up until the last line where it states `no such file or directory #include <openssl/ssl.h>`.  Than looking up that figured I need to get openssl-dev installed, but not sure if that's leading me down a rabbit hole.  Really just want to get git installed on this server if possible?

Ok, it seems I get the 443 Connection refused error anytime I try to install anything with `yum`, or `dnf` e.g.:

`yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` provides the same error pointing to the same url.

Comment: Can you reach other Rackspace sites? You can test with `curl -v https://mirror.rackspace.com/` ... look for `* Connected to mirror.rackspace.com (74.205.112.120) port 443 (#0)`

Comment: your machine is configured to reach Rackspace's "Red Hat Update Infrastructure" (RHUI) servers -- https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-update-infrastructure . "RHUI allows cloud providers to locally mirror Red Hat-hosted repository content"

Comment: My guess would be a selinux misconfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy answer: give us a call or submit a ticket and we can look at your firewall to see what's going on.

the DIY answer: since you can reach "https://github.com" but not "https://rhui.rackspace.com", you might have outbound firewall rules configured, or servers at "rhui.rackspace.com" aren't behaving.

check your outbound firewall rules. For either case below, you'll want to permit traffic to the destination host (rhui.rackspace.com) on destination port 443 with protocol TCP

1. **software firewall**
   for firewalld or iptables, try `sudo iptables -vnL OUTPUT` and look for "policy ACCEPT" (the default)
2. **hardware firewall**
   in the MyRackspace portal under Network > [Firewall Manager V2](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/firewall-manager-v2), look for the sections [100, inside, or FW-INSIDE ACL](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/firewall-manager-v2-access-list-theory-and-best-practices) which cover outbound traffic

Comment: Thanks, it was an IP Tables issue, didn't have anything in there so I added this bit here:  `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` and was able to download git after that with yum.